# VBA add parameters to a new queryDef

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

This code works fine:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, qd As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qd = db.QueryDefs("query1")
qd.Parameters("[cou]").Value = "BE"
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
Do Until rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs!title, rs!country_fk
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

But when I try to achieve the same result by CREATING a `querydef` instead of using an existing one, I get an error on the  `qd.Parameters` line.

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef
qd.SQL = "PARAMETERS [cou] Text ( 255 ); SELECT TOP 10 Title, Country_fk FROM dbo_Client WHERE Country_fk=[cou];"
qd.Parameters("[cou]").Value = "BE"

Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
Do Until rs.EOF
...
```

I noticed that `qd.Parameters.Count` = 0 and that `qd.Parameters.Add` is not allowed.
Any solution ? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example should work if you give the `QueryDef` a name.  If you want it to be a temporary `QueryDef`, use an empty string for the name ...

```vb
'Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString)
```

Comment: Indeed. I feel a bit stupid now. Shoudl I delete the question ?

Comment: I don't think so, Patrick. It should help another reader understand the `QueryDef` must be "named" (even if only an empty string as the name) in order for Access to recognize the `Parameters`.  Plus I think it is interesting; I never noticed this issue before.  :-)